# Ignore property when generating equals and hashcode

Tags: java, eclipse, guava

Let's say I have a class Customer:

```
public class Customer {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String doNotAddMeToEquals;

//Getters and Setters below

}
```

I'm using the [Guava Eclipse Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guavaeclipse/) in Eclipse to generate my equals() and hashCode() methods; however, I could just as well use the eclipse -> Source -> Generate HashCode / Equals. Either way...doesn't matter.

Is there a way to Annotate property doNotAddMeToEquals such that when I generate the equals & hashcode methods with the guava plugin that property doesn't show in the list?

Without altering the plugin or creating a template.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What Guava plugin are you referring to?  Guava does not provide a "plugin" to generate equals and hashCode methods.  It provides some utility methods to make it easier to write equals and hash code, but all you have to do to omit a particular property is...not write the bit with that particular property in the first place.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are talking about Eclipse's standard equals/hashcode generator, the dialog explicitly asks you which properties to include.

Comment: Are you sure about that Louis? http://sourceforge.net/projects/guavaeclipse/

Comment: SC And thus the question. I ran into a snag today where I just generate the equals method on everything. What I found out later was that one of the properties shouldn't have been in there. No big deal as the testcase was solid and pointed that out. So I was curious if there was a way to Annotate the property... I really don't think there is a way but ask anyways.

Comment: @JasonMcD: Ah.  That is not part of Guava, per se; someone built that on top of Guava, and the naming does not make that clear.

Comment: Lets say I wasn't using Guava at all. Just right click -> Source -> Generate Hash and Equals. That might might the question a little easy to consume.

Comment: I assume it's obvious to you that you can uncheck one of the fields as StephenC suggests when generating hash/equals like that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is something like this:

http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html

It lets you use annotations to drive what properties are included in the equals and hashcode methods.

Comment: Unfortunately the annotation is string-based, but that's not that bad as it gets compile-time checked. There were plans to switch from this to annotating fields directly, but I don't know if this has got forgotten or abandoned or whatever.

Comment: @maaartinus: Nowadays you can annotate fields directly, by using `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include` and `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`.

Answer (score 23):

Using Lombok you can exclude properties from hashcode and equals like such as:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"nameOfField"})
```

That would be in your case

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"doNotAddMeToEqualsAndHashCode"})
```