# How to ignore 1 field in Java equals() for custom object?

Tags: java, equals, lombok

I have a `Person` object which has 20 fields and stored in dynamoDB.
I want to create a new `Person` object based on some input, check if the same object exists in the Database or not. If it exists, I want to compare the 2 objects on the basis of `19 fields out of 20`. The field to ignore is a boolean flag check.

I am using `Lombok @Data` to generate the equals method.

Is there a way to do this without having to write a full fledged overriden `equals` method myself ?

Comment: You have comparison logic which you need for a very specific use case. This shouldn't be part of `equals()`. And in general putting `@Data` on an Entity.. Ouch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use Lombok's @EqualsAndHashCode in conjunction with an exclude.

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class MyObject{

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    Object fieldToExclude;

}
```

Instead of choosing which to exclude you can also opt to choose the ones you wish to include like so. All which is not annotated with Include will not be used in the equals & hashcode implementation.

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class MyObject{

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    Object fieldToInclude;

}
```

[Lombok EqualsAndHashCode documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)

Comment: Exaclty. Here is the link for detailed info https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode

Comment: If I use `@EqualsAndHashCode` along with `@Data` will that not create issues ?

Comment: Upvoted, however I never use exclusion considering it's a bit an inside-out. The inclusion strategy seems to be more natural to me (yeah, I know the OP is asking to ignore a single field).

Comment: @fluffy can you please explain a bit on the strategy that you are mentioning ?

Comment: It seems you could also go with `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"fieldToExclude"})` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506166/ignore-property-when-generating-equals-and-hashcode

Comment: @Arnaud I'd personally stay away from field names passed as string values as they are likely to be forgotten when refactoring

Comment: @newLearner I updated the answer to demo fluffy's preferred way of working

Comment: @newLearner 1) I prefer to mark fields that I'd like to be included to `toString` and `equals`/`hashCode` explicitly. For the latter I use `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` and `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include` literally telling anybody who's dealing with the code that my intention is clear (I do prefer no implicit surprises). 2) Therefore I never use "uber" annotations like `@Data`, because it is not clear how do they work in cases that are not default. Similarly, I have no idea how do `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` and `@Data` work together. :D

Comment: @NicoVanBelle Yeah, "stringed" field and methods names are evil. Sometimes I regret that Java lacks something like `myField.field` and `myMethod.method` similarly to `MyClass.class` in order to get those references to be as much actual at compile time as possible.

Comment: Can I use `@EqualsAndHashCode` along with `@Data` or will that cause issues ?

Comment: @newLearner sure you can use the two. `@EqualsAndHashCode` is more specialised so will override `@Data` for equals and hash code